Why do I need to duplicate one of the composite key columns when using two @ManyToOne relationships with composite keys in JPA/Hibernate?
I'm working on a Kotlin Spring Boot project with JPA and I have two @ManyToOne relationships that each refer to entities with composite keys. However, I’m running into an issue where I need to duplicate one of the columns from the composite key in both of the @ManyToOne relationships, even though it seems redundant. Based on the Blog of Vlad Mihalcea I use only @ManyToOne relationships.
Here’s the structure I’m dealing with:
CustomerEntity
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@IdClass(CustomerPk::class)
data class CustomerEntity(

    @Id
    val tenantUUID: UUID,

    @Id
    val customerId: Long,

    @Column(length = 30)
    var title: String? = null,

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    var lastName: String,

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    var firstName: String,

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 150)
    var address: String,

    /* output omitted for simplification *)


) {

    override fun equals(...)
    override fun hashCode()
    override fun toString()

    fun toDto(): CustomerDto = CustomerDto(
        /* output omitted for simplification */
    )
}

@NoArg
@MappedSuperclass
@Serializable
internal open class CustomerPk(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "tenant_uuid", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    protected var tenantUUID: UUID = ZERO_UUID,

    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    val customerId: Long = 0L
)

ItemEntity
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
@IdClass(ItemPK::class)
internal data class ItemEntity(
    @Id
    val tenantUUID: UUID,

    @Id
    val itemId: Long,

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    var name: String,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    var netSalesPrice: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO,

    /* output omitted for simplification */

) {
    override fun equals(...)
    override fun hashCode()
    override fun toString()
    
    fun toDto() = ItemDto(
        /* output omitted for simplification */
    )
}


@NoArg
@MappedSuperclass
@Serializable
internal open class ItemPK(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "tenant_uuid", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    protected var tenantUUID: UUID = ZERO_UUID,

    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    val itemId: Long
)

Now I need the posibility to save individual prices for a customer. Currently I'm successfully using the entity CustomerPrices where I connect the Customer with the Item and add an additional sales price attribute.
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_prices")
@IdClass(CustomerPricePK::class)
internal data class CustomerPriceEntity(
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    val item: ItemEntity,

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    val customer: CustomerEntity,

    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 2)
    var netSalesPrice: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO
) {
    override fun equals(...)
    override fun hashCode()
    override fun toString()

    fun toDto(): CustomerPriceDto = CustomerPriceDto(
        /* output omitted for simplification */
    )
}


@NoArg
@MappedSuperclass
internal open class CustomerPricePK(
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(
        JoinColumn(name = "i_tenant_uuid", referencedColumnName = "tenant_uuid", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
        JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "item_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20)", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    )
    val item: ItemEntity,

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(
        JoinColumn(name = "c_tenant_uuid", referencedColumnName = "tenant_uuid", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
        JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20)", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
    )
    val customer: CustomerEntity
)

This setup works fine because I use different names for the tenant join-columns.



i_tenant_uuid
item_id
c_tenant_uuid
customer_id
price




00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
123456
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
12345678
10.99



From the perspective of the data model this makes no sense (at least for me as an long-term Oracle devoloper), because the 2 tenant columns must always have the same value. But when I assign the same column name to both @ManyToOne relationships, JPA incorrectly uses the tenant_uuid column twice in the INSERT statement without adding the bind parameter for it.
CustomerPricePK
@NoArg
@MappedSuperclass
internal open class CustomerPricePK(
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(
        JoinColumn(name = "tenant_uuid", referencedColumnName = "tenant_uuid", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
        JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "item_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20)", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    )
    val item: ItemEntity,

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(
        JoinColumn(name = "tenant_uuid", referencedColumnName = "tenant_uuid", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
        JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20)", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
    )
    val customer: CustomerEntity
)

The generated data model is absolutely right, but the result is a wrong INSERT statement with a missing duplicated bind parameter.
2024-12-01T20:59:24.212+01:00 DEBUG 23600 --- [nio-8020-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        customer_prices
        (net_sales_price,customer_id,tenant_uuid,item_id,tenant_uuid) 
    values
        (?,?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        customer_prices
        (net_sales_price,customer_id,tenant_uuid,item_id,tenant_uuid) 
    values
        (?,?,?,?,?)
2024-12-01T20:59:24.215+01:00 TRACE 23600 --- [nio-8020-exec-4] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [NUMERIC] - [10.99]
2024-12-01T20:59:24.215+01:00 TRACE 23600 --- [nio-8020-exec-4] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1234]
2024-12-01T20:59:24.215+01:00 TRACE 23600 --- [nio-8020-exec-4] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [3] as [BINARY] - [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
2024-12-01T20:59:24.215+01:00 TRACE 23600 --- [nio-8020-exec-4] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [1001]
2024-12-01T20:59:24.225+01:00  WARN 23600 --- [nio-8020-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 07001
2024-12-01T20:59:24.225+01:00 ERROR 23600 --- [nio-8020-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : No value specified for parameter 5

Is there any possibility to "share" the TENANT_UUID column between the two entities?

This is because you mapped things this way. If all objects in a graph are going to share the same tenant ID, they in reality have a non-mapped relationship to a 'tenant'. If you aren't going to create a tenant table to handle this, you might want to consider JPA implementations support for tenancy. I don't know Hibernate all that well, but I know EclipseLink can allow you to map tenant IDs outside the model, so it can be easily included in fetches without being populated in your classes (thereby avoiding the risk of one graph referencing classes from a different tenant).
